# Limit(s) of a sequence in the discrete topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits

Why is the limit of the sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}: n \geq 1\}$ in the space $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology the empty set?

Intuitively the limit seems to be $\{0\}$ right?

Comment: The important thing is that it's the _discrete_ topology rather than the usual topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sequence of points $\{x_n\}$ in a topological space $X$ is said to converge to $x\in X$ if every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ contains all but finitely many of the points of the sequence. Without any restrictions on the topological space a sequence could have many limits or none. In this case, given any point $x$, $\{x\}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in the discrete topology i.e. every point is isolated. So does the sequence converge to any point?

Comment: Since we're working with $\mathbb{R}$ here, why is it not true that $(x- \delta , x + \delta)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in the discrete topology?

Comment: In the discrete topology every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open. In particular, every set containing $x$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. So $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, but there are way more neighbourhoods. Note that sequence intersects the neighbourhood {x} at most once for each x.

Comment: So why can we not simply take $\mathbb{R}$ to be a neighbourhood of $0$ for example and say that the sequence converges to $\{0\}$? I feel like I'm not understanding something fundamental here.Perhaps this violates the part where you said "all but finitely many of the points of the sequence"?

Comment: The definition says for a limit $x$, every (not some) neighbourhood of $x$ must contain all but fintely many points of the sequence. You only gave one such neighbourhood. I showed that no matter what $x$ you give me, I can give a neighbourhood that contains at most only one point of the sequence. Hence the sequence cannot converge to any point

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful response.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is based not on the discrete topology, but on the ordinary topology.

Here's an intuition for the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$: every real number is an island unto its own, isolated from all other islands. Jumping from the island $\frac{1}{1}$ to the island $\frac{1}{2}$ to the island $\frac{1}{3}$ and so on, never gets you anywhere near the island $0$.

Comment: I would just like to point out that I found this intuitive explanation of the discrete topology very helpful.